# Preview service generates 403 on update preview

Tags: experience-manager, web8, dxa, dxa-java

Our preview service generates the following error message in XPM:

`Unable to update the changes using OData Service. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`

The website itself runs, we have CU1 installed on CME and are running preview service from hotfix 8.1.1.2317. The preview service is registered in the discovery service. In the Windows `Event Viewer` of the CMS machine we see the following messages alternated:

```
Unable to update the changes using OData Service.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
 Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService Errorcode: 1003 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
  at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.MakeMemoryStream(Stream stream)
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
  at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.BatchRequest(Boolean replaceOnUpdate)
  at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
  at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
  at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
  at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.FastTrackPublishingService.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
  at SyncInvokePreview(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

[18:01]  
Unable to update the changes using OData Service.
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
 Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService Errorcode: 1003 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
  at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.BatchRequest(Boolean replaceOnUpdate)
  at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
  at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
  at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
  at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.FastTrackPublishingService.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
  at SyncInvokePreview(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Yet the log of the preview service are empty.

Could anyone here give me a pointer where to look to fix this because I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Sounds like a firewall or network issue.

Comment: Hi Nuno. I can access the preview service from multiple machines, including the CMS. So I guess that too is a dead end.

Comment: Did you configure your CD Environment in Topology Manager to use `cmuser` as OAuth Client ID?  If you accidentally used  `cduser`, you will get  this error, because that user don't have permissions to do updates.